# GUID column used to update a table - should it be indexed?

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing

I'm working on a database where I retrieve the ID of my record after I've added it by saving and retrieving a known GUID.  My application runs on both SQL Server and Oracle, so I can't use @@IDENTITY*.

Say for example, I add a new address:

```
ID (identity column in SQL Server;sequenced/trigger column in Oracle)
... address data... (street, town, postcode, etc.)
GUID
```

I get the ID back by doing the following:

```
1. INSERT INTO ADDRESS (... address details, GUID = {some new GUID value})
2. SELECT ID FROM ADDRESS WHERE GUID = {my GUID value}
3. UPDATE ADDRESS SET GUID = NULL WHERE GUID = {my GUID value}
```

At part 1, I'm adding the address details and setting the GUID value in the database; at part 2, I'm getting my ID back and at part 3, I'm removing the GUID value from the database (to avoid the very unlikely event of a duplicate GUID).

When I look at the SQL Server 2008 Estimated Execution Plan for the third bit, it shows the following path if I have no index on the GUID column:

[image: Image shows the estimated execution plan where there's no index on the GUID column]

and the following path if I have an index on the GUID column:

[image: Image shows the estimated execution plan where there's an index on the GUID column]

My question is: I realise that the scan shown in the first image is not as good as the seek shown in the second image, but would the fact that the GUID column is essentially empty 99.999% of the time mean that I shouldn't index the field, because it would be fragmented all the time and would waste resources?  Or would the index still help because it would easily show me where my one-and-only GUID is that I just added, rather than having to do a whole scan for it?

**In summary: Given the fact that the GUIDs are added and then immediately removed, is there any point in indexing the GUID column?**

*In fact, the design is not my own, so I'm unable to use a different method; however, you should see that the design of my particular database does not affect my overall question.

Comment: In SQL you can use NEWID to select a new, distinct GUID. There are problems with NEWID and indexing though because a NEWID is random so it can appear anywhere in the binary tree of an index. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx

Comment: What for are you using such technique for receiving identity column value? In MS SQL and I beleive in Oracle too there are much more convenient and quick way to get ID. Use stored proc for record addition with different techniques for Oracle and MS SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you absolutely need to index your column for what you're doing. Use a filtered index in SQL Server (not sure what is the Oracle equivalent):

```
create index AddressGuid on ADDRESS(GUID) where GUID is not NULL;
```

But there is abetter way: use OUTPUT/RETURNING clause of INSERT. Both [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) and [Oracle](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/returninginto_clause.htm) supports it (each its own flavour) and you no longer need the GUID workaround.

Comment: Great, and thanks for the fast response!  I'll definitely check out the output/returning clauses; I do have a certain amount of influence, so perhaps that's the direction we can take in the future.

Comment: Hi Ramus, after doing some further reading, it seems the RETURNING INTO clause in Oracle is only supported by Oracle 10g and above, which is why we can't use it =(  Thanks anyway though; definitely something to consider for when our last customer migrates from Oracle 9i.

Comment: Actually, after doing some of my own research on an Oracle 9i database, RETURNING INTO works fine... now I'm very confused, haha!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't index that column, each of those `SELECT` and `UPDATE` statements will have to scan the whole table to find your row. If that's not what you want, you'll have to index. I wouldn't bother setting that `GUID` column to NULL, though.

Comment: Thanks Gabe. Interestingly, I had a discussion with my technical lead about why we set the GUID column to null shortly before posting my question.  I gotta say I agree with you on that, but hopefully we'll move towards using Remus' output/returning suggestion eventually.